# Pubnub function xhr module is calling server endpoint multiple times ( it should call only one time )

Tags: javascript, ajax, pubnub

I have been using pubnub for realtime communication between mobile devices. 
The scenario I am creating is as follows:

1. The sender mobile device will publish a message to pubnub.
2. The message will call a On Before Function PubNub Function where original
   message is sent to laravel endpoint where it is persisted and the
   database record id is added to the message and published to the subscriber.

(Laravel endpoint is called using `xhr` module from PN Function)

The issue I am facing is that my laravel endpoint is called approximately 7 to 12 times for each publish the message.

Below is my onBefore PubNub function.

```js
export default (request) => { 
    console.log('intial message: ',request.message);
    const kvstore = require('kvstore');
    const xhr = require('xhr');
    const http_options = {
        "timeout": 5000, // 5 second timeout.
        "method": "POST",
        "body": "foo=bar&baz=faz"
    };

    const url = "redacted_backend_url";

    return xhr.fetch(url,http_options).then((x) => {
        console.log('Messages after calling ajax: ',request.message.content);
        // here i am changing the message
        request.message.content = 'hello world'; 
        return request.ok();
    }).catch(err=>console.log(err)) ;
}
```

Please identify what exactly wrong.

Comment: Can you show the logs that show it is calling more than once?

Comment: We got your support ticket and we'll continue to work with you there and respond back with an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Function Wildcard Channel Binding

Your Function is bound to channel `'*'` which of course means capture all publishes to all channels. What you don't know is that `console.log` in a Function publishes the message to a channel that looks like this: `blocks-output-kpElEbxa9VOgYMJQ.77042688368579w9`

And the Functions output window is subscribed to that channel to display your `console.log`'s. So when the Function is invoked, it publishes a message to the `console.log`s channel which is captured by your Function, which calls `console.log` and eventually, a configured recursion limit is hit to protect you from getting into an infinite loop.

So if you were to change your channel binding to something like `foo.*` and publish to a channel like `foo.bar`, this undesired recursion would be avoided. In production, the console.logs should be removed, too, and it would not cause this to happen.

Additionally, you could implement some channel filter condition at the top of the your Function to prevent it from further execution your Function code:

```
if (channel.startsWith("blocks-output"))
    return request.ok()
}
```